# User Input not saving in Database after using AbstractUser model and Custom Signup form

Tags: python, django-models, django-templates

I have custom user model that inherits from the AbstractUser and also have a custom signup form that means I don't want to use the built-in form.as_p. Sign up doesn't save users to the database when try signing up but when I use the built-in form (form.as_p), it works well. I need someone to help me fix this.

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
     username = None
     email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)
     USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
  
     objects = CustomeUserManager()

     def __str__(self:
         return self.email
```

managers.py

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
"""
Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
for authentication instead of usernames.
"""
def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    """
    Create and save a user with the given email and password.
    """
    if not email:
        raise ValueError(_("The Email must be set"))
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    return user

def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    """
    Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
    """
    extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", True)
    extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)
    extra_fields.setdefault("is_active", True)

    if extra_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
        raise ValueError(_("Superuser must have is_staff=True."))
    if extra_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
        raise ValueError(_("Superuser must have is_superuser=True."))
    return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

forms.py

```
class CustomUserCreationsForm(forms.ModelForm):

password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class Meta:
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ('email',)

def clean_password2(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
    return password2

def save(self, commit=True):
    # Save the provided password in hashed format
    user = super().save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    user.active = False #Send  confirmation email
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
# Create a new user form.
    form = CustomUserCreationsForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('home')
else:
    form = CustomUserCreationsForm(request.POST)

return render(request, 'Custome/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Register form when I use the built-in form -
register.html

```
{% extends 'Custome/base.html' %}

{% block content %}


   <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.as_p }}

     <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
   </form>
{% endblock %}
```

and Register form when I use a custom register.html -
register.html

```
{% extends 'Custome/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">

      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password">

      <label for="password_confirm">Confirm Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password_confirm" name="password_confirm" placeholder="Confirm your password">

      <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
   </form>

{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from .views import home, register

urlpatterns = [
   path('', home, name='home'),
   path('register/', register, name='register'),
]
```

Comment: I found the solution. I realize the password1 and password2 names in my forms.py are different from the password names I have in my custom register.html file. So there was no connection, I guess.